# get class name from mongoid criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

```
irb(main):019:0> a = Admin.first
=> #<Admin _id: 514b318da61654dd05000002, email: "email@email.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$b.cWtfPNgUcCubJRX2vjAO6vEsds9OTGO2tn6Lfz2cBU.mwTYsHw.">

irb(main):020:0> a.class.name
=> "Admin"

irb(main):021:0> a = Admin.all
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {}
  options:  {}
  class:    Admin
  embedded: false>

irb(main):022:0> a.class.name
=> "Mongoid::Criteria"
```

How I get the **model name** inside **"Mongoid::Criteria"** class?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with this:

```
a.klass   #=> Admin
or
a.klass.name #=> "Admin"
```